# Create validation error with two possible conditions

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms

I can create a if not statement with one condition. This works -

```
if not "ABC124" in voucher:
     raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid Voucher")
return voucher
```

And this works -

```
if not "ABC124" in voucher:
     raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid Voucher")
return voucher
```

But this doesn't work -

```
 if not "ABC124" in voucher or if not "ABC123" in voucher:
      raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid Voucher")
 return voucher
```

And this doesn't work -

```
if not "ABC124" in voucher or not "ABC123" in voucher :
     raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid Voucher")
return voucher
```

How do I make an if statement with two conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the [*De Morgan's laws* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), you need to use **`and`** as an operator, not <s>`or`</s>:

```
if 'ABC124' not in voucher and 'ABC123' not in voucher :
     raise forms.ValidationError('Invalid Voucher')
return voucher
```

So only if the vouches does *not* contain `'ABC124'` *and* it does not contain `'ABC123'` either, it will raise an error.

---

> **Note**: It is more readable to write `x not in y` than to write
> <s>`not x in y`</s>.